# Query to check if field exists and then return the result set

Tags: mysql

I dont know how can i explain it, may be this example garbage query can help.

```
SELECT if_exists(Fieldname) * FROM my table name
```

I am trying to select all the rows of the database only if `Fieldname` field is present.

Can you help me out

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Pekka, please see the explanation

Comment: @downvoter, Can you please clarify the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SHOW columns from `yourtable` where field='yourfield'
```

You will get a empty rows, if you dont have that field in that table.

Comment: What if the field is dynamically generated, this does not universally solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following code in plain PHP should work fine:

```
$chkcol = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 1"); 
$mycol = mysql_fetch_array($chkcol); 
if(isset($mycol['column_name'])) 
  $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name`");
else
  $results = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ‘you_table_name’ AND COLUMN_NAME = ‘FIELDNAME’)
 BEGIN
    select fieldname from your_table_name
 END
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the column fieldname must exists even if the subquery is never executed. But If I see your example you want to use all columns so if you replace 
    select fieldname from your_table_name
with 
    select * from your_table_name then it should work. Can't test right now.

Comment: The problem is that field name is written in backtick. Write it instead in single quotes like this SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ‘you_table_name’ AND COLUMN_NAME = 'FIELDNAME'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-columns.html) expression.

Also i found this solution: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4663

Comment: I could use show columns, but i run the query from php, so I am looking for shortest process first

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this. Sorry, cannot test if the syntax is OK though.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name=table AND column_name=column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a query I used: it returns no column, if the column doesn't exist.
It shouldn't be much work to change it, for you needs.

```
SET @VAR_SQL := Concat('SELECT first_row',CONCAT(IFNULL((SELECT CONCAT(',',COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'my_column'),'')),' FROM my_table;');
PREPARE QUERY_STATEMENT FROM @VAR_SQL;
EXECUTE QUERY_STATEMENT;
```