# Is it possible to dynamically select a column name in MYSQL where the column name is 1 of N known values?

Tags: mysql

I fear the answer will be a straight 'no', but I was wondering if it's possible to do something such as the following in MySQL:

`SELECT (title||label||name) FROM table`

i.e Select a single column, which may be called `title`, `label` or `name`, from `table`.

Reason being: the query will be dynamically generated where `table` is known but (due to reasons beyond my control) there is no consistent naming convention in the other tables.

Comment: How do you know which field you want?  Or do you just want to select the whichever one exists?  Might this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9086503

Comment: I'd like to select whichever exists (if more than one exists, then the first match), or if doesn't exist to fail gracefully. I guess I could do a `DESCRIBE` and check that way in PHP, but would prefer a single query.

Comment: How is the query being generated?  Can you just make a lookup table?  Like `if(table === 'books'){ field = 'title' }`?

Comment: Sadly, all I can know for sure is the table name and that the columns will be A, B or C. I don't know what table has which column, unfortunately.

Comment: It's not like they are changing, couldn't you just look in the database manually, then hard-code a mapping between table and column?  Because, other than running a query for each and seeing which doesn't fail, I can't think of another solution.

Comment: This particular implementation is part of a framework/library so will be used on many databases and writing a config file for each app will defeat the purpose. Thanks for your thoughts though - it might just not be possible!

Comment: Well, you could use `DESCRIBE` before you generate the query, so you know which field to use.

Comment: This sounds like a disaster in the making

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably just do that. Thanks again, very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does the trick.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE_NAME' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('name', 'label', 'title') into @colname;
SET @table = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ',@colname,' FROM ', @table);

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Inspiration here : [Dynamic conversion of string into column name. MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282718/dynamic-conversion-of-string-into-column-name-mysql)

Comment: Yes, it does indeed do the trick! I've opted for a change in logic but will accept this answer as it answers the question at hand. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. For many columns `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', ') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE_NAME' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%name%' INTO @colnames;`

Comment: FIX. `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME) SEPARATOR ', ') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE_NAME' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%name%' INTO @colnames;`

Answer (score 4):

I completely agree with [@Strawberry's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572848/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-select-a-column-name-in-mysql-where-the-column-nam#comment25568509_17572848) that "*this sounds like a disaster in the making*"—it's a *very* poor design strategy and I strongly recommend finding an alternative solution.  However, it's an interesting challenge… this is my solution:

```
SELECT COALESCE(title,label,name) col FROM `table` NATURAL LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT NULL title, NULL label, NULL name
) t WHERE COALESCE(title,label,name) IS NOT NULL
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3a9a/1).

Note that if the record data is `NULL`, no record will be returned.

Comment: I too agree - it's a horrendous mess! This is a client's project and I've been tasked with 'fixing' it. *facepalm*

Comment: So, it selects them as NULL, then if one happens to exist, it replaces the NULL value?  Neat.

Answer (score -1):

Write the query statement dynamically using the programming language. Then execute the database function using that query. Problem solved!

Answer (score -2):

select     student_id, aq.question,
case aq.question_id
when 1 then ans_question_1
when 2 then ans_question_2
end Answer
from       answers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).