# mysql select statement to handle non existent field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql query that works fine on 1 database but fails on another because the 2nd database does not have 1 of the fields in the select clause. Is there any way to have 1 single query that returns the right value in the first database but simply returns NULL or empty in the 2nd query e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl.a, tbl.b, tbl.c
FROM DB as tbl
```

i.e. imagine that `tbl.c` exists in database 1 but not database 2

Comment: is it in a stored procedure?

Comment: unfortunately not. It seems my question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062815/mysql-select-a-field-as-null-if-not-existent-in-table - seems like this is not a simple thing to do in mysql.

Comment: what is it then, php?